# How to permanently dismiss error display in react native app

Tags: ios, react-native, native, react-native-ios, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using a ask for iOS application which is written in react native but I don't have good knowledge of react native.

I just want to know that is there any way to permanently disable the error view shows in react native app 
[enter link description here](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRM2tUwcyw4ejrRPjTNUcNfOZQ2H5Lu_9YACqEYfDF26rjYq49L)
Like we can disable the warning  by this line..

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

If there is any way to disable the error view please help me..

Comment: Do you know the error console is not shown in the actual production app right? Why would you want to disable it?

Comment: @sfratini but in my app it's appear many times but everything working fine. I don't much about react native that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: you can't disable errors... It means app has crashed. If you build a production version, app will crash. If you saw the red screen, it means something is really wrong. But you can use try-catch to show a error message to user

Answer (score 0):

In assemble release or prod release there wont be any error shown  like the one you just posted. But in debug or dev environment it's always recommended to actually be shown the errors so to prevent the app from crashing in production.  And those error screen actually helps to identify where the code went wrong. But as you have already done disableYellow box to true which mutes the warnings in the app but not the errors since in dev errors are important to correct the code.